# IoT Light Switch

Tags: remote-control

I'm getting started with some light IoT at my workplace.  My requirement is to control several light switches/dimmers through C#.  There is a lot of IoT information out there and ZigBee looks promising.  DOes anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking for smart light switches/dimmers that you can control with C#, correct? What have you looked at and why don't they fit your needs?

Comment: My question is vague because I don't know enough to be more specific. Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I spent yesterday afternoon googling around and I was honestly overwhelmed. I think I know less now than I did when I started. I think Zigbee might be the way to go but I'm not sure.